# How to focus on imgs with same classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus

Guys i tried to search but i couldn't understand any of the answers explanations, so here we go. I got three imgs (links to facebook, twitter and instagram) and i want to focus on the img when the cursor is above her. It works, but only on the first image. Any tips ?

Here the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="eight columns img-footer">
    <img src="img/fb.png" class="img" onMouseOver="focaImg(event.type)" onMouseOut="focaImg(event.type)">
    <img src="img/twitter.png" class="img" onMouseOver="focaImg(event.type)" onMouseOut="focaImg(event.type)">
    <img src="img/insta.png" class="img" onMouseOver="focaImg(event.type)" onMouseOut="focaImg(event.type)">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function focaImg(e){
    var img = document.querySelector(".img");

    if(e == "mouseover"){
        img.style.opacity = "1";

        img.focus();
    }else{
        img.style.opacity = "0.5";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j4034w5w/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the CSS :hover selector?

```
.img {
    opacity:0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

You can seen an example in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0f21vxLz/1/), and read more about CSS image transparency over at [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp).